# USB Printer Sometimes Shows Up As Printer Name (Copy 1)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, usb, printer

Is it possible to prevent a printer from being 'installed' in Windows XP/Vista as Printer Name (Copy 1) when it already is in Printers as just Printer Name after unplugging and plugging in the USB cable to the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'Safely remove hardware' feature before disconnecting the printer.

Comment: That would be ideal, but if a user unplugs the printer inadvertently then that option is gone. No way to prevent it then?

Comment: sounds like PEBCAK to me. :)

Comment: @Molly: Heh generally I would agree, but the reason I ask is because we use the Dymo LabelWriter 400 Turbo for our application and the application refers to the printer by its name so it knows where to print (defining USB port is nearly impossible). so if it has Copy 1 on the name, it does not match.

Comment: @Roboto - i know ... but the problem with disconnecting USB printers only to find another copy installed after reconnect is a known issue and inconvenience, i don't think there is a satisfying solution, other than safely disconnecting the printer the proper way.

Comment: @Molly: Gotcha.. Dymo said it was a Windows-problem as well just thought I'd check SuperUser. Thanks